# dropdown onchange action cannot work in dynamic form generation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

#### Problem

I am generating a form dynamically by clicking a button. in that form i have invoice dropdown while changing the invoice the invoice amount value printed in next text box. this action can be done in ajax. and my problem is change function is not working.

#### Code

```
var i = 0;
var wrapper = $("#addcollection_div");
$('#addnew').click(function (e) {
    var customer = $("#clientname").val();
i += 1;
        if (i == 1) {
                $.post('includes/ajax_timesheet.php', {'cust': customer, 'action': 'getinvoice'}, function (data) {
                    $("#invno").html(data);
                    $("#addcollection_div").show();
                });
        }else if(i > 1){
            e.preventDefault();
                $(wrapper).append(
                            '<tr>'+
                            '<td size="5">' + '<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" size="5" id="" value="'+i+'" readonly >' + '</td>'+
                            '<td size="25">'+
                                '<select id="invno'+i+'" name="invno[]"  class="select-mini student" >'+
                                    '<option Selected value="Select">Select Invoice No </option>'+
                                '</select>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td size="10">'+
                                '<input type="text" id="inv_amt'+i+'" name="inv_amt[]"  class="form-control" size="25" value="" readonly>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td size="10">'+
                                '<input type="text" id="due_amt'+i+'" name="due_amt[]"  class="form-control"  value="" readonly>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="cheque_amt'+i+'" name="cheque_amt[]"  class="form-control"  value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="12">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="tds'+i+'" name="tds[]"  class="form-control"  value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="12" >'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="deduction'+i+'" name="deduction[]"  class="form-control"  value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="12">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="retention'+i+'" name="retention[]"  class="form-control"  value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="12">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                               '<input type="text" id="remarks'+i+'" name="remarks[]"  class="form-control"  value="">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            //'<td><a href="#" class="remove_field" >Remove</a></td>'+
                            '<td><a href="#" class="remove_field" ><input type="image" src="../../css/images/delete_btn.gif" name="deletedep" border="0" ></a></td>'+
                            '</tr>');
            
                $.post('includes/ajax_timesheet.php', {'cust': customer, 'action': 'getinvoice'}, function (data) {
                    $("#invno"+i).html(data);
                }); 
        }
        
});


$("#invno"+i).change(function () {

    var invno = $("#invno"+i).val();
    $.post('includes/ajax_timesheet.php', {'invoiceno': invno, 'action': 'getinv_total'}, function (data) {
        $("#inv_amt"+i).val($.trim(data));
    });

    $.post('includes/ajax_timesheet.php', {'invoiceno': invno, 'action': 'getaddue_amt'}, function (data) {
        $("#due_amt"+i).val($.trim(data));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', '.invo', function () {
  alert('test');
  });
```

Comment: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#invo"+i` error is coming